# android MediaPlayer black screen onResume

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an android app that plays a video on a scalable screen. 
For the container I am using a fragment which contains a TextureView.

In the TextureView I play a video using MediaPlayer object. I have overridden the onPause() and onResume() methods of the UserVideoFragment class to pause/resume video.

The logic is that if the video is scaled down then the video should be paused even on returning to the screen.
If video is fullscreen then the video should play.

Problem I am facing is **when user preses home and then returns to activity with fragment in scaled down mode the <strike>mediaplayer</strike> TextureView displays a black screen**.

Here is the code

MainActivity.java

```
private boolean recordingVideo;
private float scaleFactor;
private int marginPixels;
private long animDuration;

private Button btnRecord;
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
private UserVideoFragment fragmentUserVideo;
private ExpertRecordingFragment fragmentExpertRecording;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    UIUtils.hideActionAndStatusBar(getSupportActionBar(), getWindow());

    init();

    btnRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

    btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new RecordButtonListener());
}

private void init(){
    recordingVideo = false;
    scaleFactor = 0.2f;
    marginPixels = 32;
    animDuration = 250;
}


private class RecordButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        fragmentUserVideo = (UserVideoFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentUserVideo);
        fragmentExpertRecording = (ExpertRecordingFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentExpertRecording);

        View userVideoView = fragmentUserVideo.getView();
        if(!recordingVideo){
            animateView(userVideoView, 0f, userVideoView.getHeight(), scaleFactor, marginPixels, marginPixels, animDuration);
        }

        if(recordingVideo){
            animateView(userVideoView, 0f, userVideoView.getHeight(), 1f, 0, 0, animDuration);
        }

        recordingVideo = !recordingVideo;
        fragmentUserVideo.onExpertVideoRecordingStarted(recordingVideo);
        fragmentExpertRecording.onExpertVideoRecordingStarted(recordingVideo);
    }
}

private void animateView(View view, float pivotX, float pivotY,
                         float scalingFactor, int marginPixelsX, int marginPixelsY, long duration){
    view.setPivotX(pivotX);
    view.setPivotY(pivotY);
    view.animate()
            .scaleX(scalingFactor)
            .scaleY(scalingFactor)
            .x(marginPixelsX)
            .y(-marginPixelsY)
            .setDuration(duration);
}

public interface OnExpertVideoRecordingStartedListener{
    public void onExpertVideoRecordingStarted(boolean recording);
}
```

UserVideoFragment.java

```
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private TextureView userVideoTextureView;
private boolean mediaSourceSet;
private int mediaPausePosition;
private boolean recording;



@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_video, container, false);;

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayerOnCompletionListener());
    mediaSourceSet = false;
    mediaPausePosition = 0;
    recording = false;
    userVideoTextureView = (TextureView) view.findViewById(R.id.userVideoTextureView);
    userVideoTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(new UserVideoTextureViewListener());


    return view;
}



@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        if(recording) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPausePosition);
            userVideoTextureView.requestLayout();
        }

        if(!recording){
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

private class UserVideoTextureViewListener implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener{

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {
        Surface mediaSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
        try{
            if(!mediaSourceSet){
                //mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://videocdn.bodybuilding.com/video/mp4/62000/62792m.mp4");
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(mediaSurface);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                UIUtils.adjustAspectRatio(userVideoTextureView, mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight());
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });
                mediaSourceSet = true;
            }

            if(mediaSourceSet){
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(mediaSurface);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                UIUtils.adjustAspectRatio(userVideoTextureView, mediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(), mediaPlayer.getVideoHeight());
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int width, int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {

    }
}

private class MediaPlayerOnCompletionListener implements MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener{

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    }
}



public void onExpertVideoRecordingStarted(boolean recording){
        if(recording){
            if(mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                mediaPausePosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        }

        if(!recording){
            if(mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }

        this.recording = recording;
    }
```

Comment: You mean TextureView displays a black screen not media player.

Comment: I am not so sure. That maybe the case. I tried calling TextureView.requestLayout() without which the textureview is not displayed at all.

How can I make sure that the media player displays the video frame where it was paused when onResume() is called in scaled mode?